# Generating preprocessed files using bcc32

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, borland-c++

Does anyone know what the command line option is to generate a preprocessed file using `bcc32.exe` (version 5.6.4)? I know that using `gcc` you can use `-E` to generate `.i` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use bcc32.exe but cpp32.exe.

See [here](http://pjtsalina.codigolivre.org.br/doc/c/C++Builder5Examples/WinTools/CPP32.TXT) for more information on its commandline options or use "cpp32.exe -?".

Comment: BTW, the option is -P. So:
> cpp32.exe -P main.cpp